# A-close data mining implementation

Tags: data-mining, implementation, apriori

I need to compare the Apriori and the A-close algorithm on a dataset so I need the implementations of both algorithms. I can find implementions of the Apriori algorithm but I can't find implementations of the A-close algorithm. It's saves me lots of time when I find a implementation of the A-close algorithm. Does someone has the implementation of this algorithm and wants to share it or some tips for finding this implementation?